# How to split number by hyphen

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How could i split a number on this format: xxxxxxxx to this xxxx-xxxx in excel?

Comment: why can't you just format it?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1775-excel-add-dashes-to-phone-number.html#a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to start by stating that I believe Ron Rosenfeld's comment to be absolutely correct.  Adding a dash to the number does two things:

1. Changes it from being a number to being text
2. Increases the amount of information that needs to be stored

you are usually far better off changing the display formatting than actually inserting the dash/hyphen between the first and last 4 digits.

Having said that, if you have a reason to actually insert the dash, you can use the following formula assuming your Data is in A1.  Place the formula in your required cell and copy down as necessary:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4)
```